# Resize VisNetwork along with section using flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, vis.js

I've positioned Vis-network within flex sections.

You can see the full code here: https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/XWdgzoB (try moving elements down)

The problem is whenever I try to resize the height of the section manually to '1000px' or whatever value the height of the diagram stays the same. When I push height directly to diagram sections resize properly. But this is problematic when I put something on the right side that expands the main section, and the diagram stays put with the default size. I tried to use autosize for vis.js but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

```js
var options = {
    "interaction": {
        "hover": true
    },
    "autoResize": true
};
```

I tried height/width 100% and it seems it treats min-height as max-height as well.

```html
.diagram {
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid unset;
}

.vis-network:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```
<div class="defaultSection overflowHidden">
    <div class="defaultSectionHead">
        <div class="defaultSectionText"><a name="Diagram - Defaults">Diagram - Defaults </a>&nbsp;<a id="show_192677063" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('192677063'); " style="display:none">(Show)</a><a id="hide_192677063" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide('192677063'); ">(Hide)</a></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:1000px" name="192677063" id="192677063" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent">
        <div id="192677063" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent collapsable">
            <div class="defaultSection overflowHidden">
                <div class="defaultSectionHead">
                    <div class="defaultSectionText"><a> </a>&nbsp;<a id="show_376758632" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('376758632'); " style="display:none">(Show)</a><a id="hide_376758632" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide('376758632'); " style="display:none">(Hide)</a></div>
                </div>
                <div name="376758632" id="376758632" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent">
                    <div id="376758632" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent collapsable">
                        <div class="diagram" style="position:relative">
                            <div class="diagram" style="position:absolute" id="Diagram-02jbghuv"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexPanel overflowHidden defaultPanel">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess it could be related to position relative/absolute - but if i remove it diagram resize itself automatically slowly which looks very weird.

```
<div class="diagram" style="position:relative">
    <div class="diagram" style="position:absolute" id="Diagram-02jbghuv"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

The end goal for me is to have a diagram resize automatically if something on the right side expands, and shrink if it's smaller (min 400px), unless I force the diagram to a static value. Also if I set sections/panels to something bigger I would like diagram to resize itself to match it.

Right now it seems I am fighting flex to position it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the path from the element with height:1000px to the element containing the diagram, there is a div element which does not propagate the height.
This can be fixed by setting `display:flex` on that element, see css class `fix1` and its corresponding html element in the code below.

The other css class, `fix2`, shows how you can make the right panel autosize its width (based on the width of its content and a minimum width you choose, 600px in this example) a have the left panel take up the remaining space.

```
.fix1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fix2 {
    flex-basis: auto !important;
    min-width:600px;
}
```

```
<div class="defaultSection overflowHidden">
    <div class="defaultSectionHead">
        <div class="defaultSectionText"><a name="Diagram - Defaults">Diagram - Defaults </a>&nbsp;<a id="show_192677063" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('192677063'); " style="display:none">(Show)</a><a id="hide_192677063" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide('192677063'); ">(Hide)</a></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:1000px" name="192677063" id="192677063" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent">
        <div id="192677063" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent collapsable">
            <div class="defaultSection overflowHidden fix1">
                <div class="defaultSectionHead">
                    <div class="defaultSectionText"><a> </a>&nbsp;<a id="show_376758632" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('376758632'); " style="display:none">(Show)</a><a id="hide_376758632" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide('376758632'); " style="display:none">(Hide)</a></div>
                </div>
                <div name="376758632" id="376758632" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent">
                    <div id="376758632" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden defaultSectionContent collapsable">
                        <div class="diagram" style="position:relative">
                            <div class="diagram" style="position:absolute" id="Diagram-02jbghuv"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexPanel overflowHidden defaultPanel fix2">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the full code [here](https://codepen.io/mcernak/pen/LYNjgJy)

Comment: Great - thank you. It doesn't seem to impact anything else as far as I can tell. I've added fix1 to defaultSection class.

Comment: Actually it has an impact on other things. When you add your fix to other cases: https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/rNeGaRP things are affected. Notice class Section-ihc5826 which is a copy - and notice how left section header is totally messed up.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail in what way is the section header messed up? I've noticed following differences between the left section header and the other headers: it is oriented vertically, it does not have rounded corners and it has a different text color.

Comment: I applied your fix1 to the code pen above. Please check now. I added it for each section (that is my goal - to not have to customize it). The first section is broken, the rest is ok.

Comment: Is this the design you wanted: https://codepen.io/mcernak/pen/VwaMKRv ?

Comment: If so, just replace the css classes used for the left section with the ones used for all the other sections (e.g. replace Section-b5nipkf with defaultSection, SectionHead-b5nipkf with defaultSectionHead etc.).
Since you are using different css classes for the left section and the other sections, you get a different output.

Comment: No I wanted what you saw in the code pen before I added fix1. Header of the first section  is oriented vertically and is on the left side, while others are oriented horizontally. For horizontal way your fix seems to work. For vertical - it doesn't.

Comment: Rename fix1 to fix7 in line 267  and you will see how things change and what I want to "keep" while having diagram resize properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220836/discussion-between-mcernak-and-madboy).